# Como incluir arquivo JSON dentro de um .JS

Tags: javascript, html, json

Já procurei aqui no fórum, peguei exemplos prontos em outros sites, mas nenhum adiantou para mim.

Como diz no título, eu não estou conseguindo fazer essa ligação de um arquivo `.json` pra dentro do arquivo `.js`.

Esse é o meu arquivo `script.js`

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'dados.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
```

meu arquivo `dados.json`:

```
{
  "rgV":"50.000.000-0",
  "veiculoV":"Carro",
  "dataV":"20/08/2018",
  "blocoV":"A","aptoV":"12",
  "placaV":"DWK - 3818",
  "horaV":"13:18h",
  "nomeV":"Nome Sobrenome",
  "empresaV":"Alguma Empresa"
}
```

E no meu HTML, eu chamo a página script.js assim:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Enfim, eu abro o console e o navegador não me retorna nenhum erro... Desculpe se não fui muito claro. Resumindo tudo, não estou conseguindo incluir o arquivo `JSON` dentro do meu `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, se alguém precisar, segue o código:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("dados.json", function(text){
    var dados = JSON.parse(text);

    var foto = document.getElementById('foto');
    foto.innerHTML = dados.fotoV;

    var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
    nome.innerHTML = dados.nomeV;

    var bloco = document.getElementById('bloco');
    bloco.innerHTML = dados.blocoV + " - " + dados.aptoV;

    var rg = document.getElementById('rg');
    rg.innerHTML = dados.rgV;

    var veiculo = document.getElementById('veiculo');
    veiculo.innerHTML = dados.veiculoV + ", " + dados.placaV;

    var empresa = document.getElementById('empresa');
    empresa.innerHTML = dados.empresaV;

    var datahora = document.getElementById('datahora');
    datahora.innerHTML = dados.dataV + " - " + dados.horaV;

    console.log(dados);
});
```